# Editing the Ui of vscode Terminal

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am absolutely new to Vscode and i dont know how to configure it.
and when i first installed vscode the terminal tabs looked like this

[image: original terminal tabs]

But it looks like this now

[image: terminal tabs now]

Please can anyone tell me how to get back ui design of the tab selection and how did this happen.

Comment: they have changed the terminal UI, like they do with other parts of the UI, use an old version of VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your [JSON settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) and set:

```json
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": false
```

Or disable it in the settings UI page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove installed theme.

Please review below link to find solution:
[click here](https://kalkus.dev/2020/04/03/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code/)